# How to receive multiple responses from UDP broadcast

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp

I have a case in which i need to send a broadcast a UDP request in the wifi on a specific port and the specific devices i am calling should return some info so i can determine how much are they in this network. 
So far i have this:

```
public class UDP extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String text = "";
        int server_port = 7432;
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = null;
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
            clientSocket.setSoTimeout(5);
            InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255");
            byte[] sendData = ("02904").getBytes();
            byte[] receiveData = new byte[12];
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, server_port);
            clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
            receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            Log.e("Receiving response", "Response");
            text = new String(receivePacket.getData());
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            Log.e("Receiving response", "Response");
            assert receivePacket != null;
            text = new String(receivePacket.getData());
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Receiving response", "Response");
            assert receivePacket != null;
            text = new String(receivePacket.getData());
            clientSocket.close();
        }
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        Log.e("Socket response", s);
    }
}
```

Testing with 1 device in the network is returning weird triangles with question marks in them (i am not sure but i guess something with encoding) but my actual problem is that i do not know how to get a list for example and fill it up with all the devices that responded. How to get every response and save it as a different response so i can parse them? 
Everything i know for the request is in the code. Response will be `byte[]` with 12 as size and device specific info in it.